# Room как работать с бд не в ui потоке

Tags: android, android-room

При получении сообщения через brodcastreciver нужно обращаться к бд и обновлять данные на экране. В ui потоке обращаться к бд нельзя, попробовал сделать через Flowable. Работает как то криво.

```
@Dao
public interface PushDataDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pushdata")
    Flowable<List<PushData>> getAll();
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pushdata WHERE idFromServer = :idServer")
    Flowable<PushData> loadByIdServer(String idServer);
```

При создании активити загружаю все что есть в бд

```
db.userDao()
                .getAll()
                .distinctUntilChanged()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<List<PushData>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(List<PushData> pushData) {
                        for (PushData data : pushData) {
                            LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.constraint);
                            final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_request_work, null);
                            ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.address))).setText(data.area);
                            ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.description))).setText(data.name + " " + data.tel);
                            ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.rectangleNumber))).setText(data.number);
                            (view.findViewById(R.id.agreeBtn)).setOnClickListener(view1 -> agreeRequestWork());
                            (view.findViewById(R.id.disagreeBtn)).setOnClickListener(view1 -> disagreeRequestWork());
                            layout.addView(view);
                            viewMap.put(data.idFromServer, view);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

И далее когда приходит сообщение добавляю на экран то, что добавилось в бд

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String command = intent.getStringExtra("command");
            //добавление новой заявки на экран
            if(command.equals("/order_new")) {
                String id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
                AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
                db.userDao()
                        .loadByIdServer(id)
                        .distinctUntilChanged()
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<PushData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(PushData pushData) {
                        LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.constraint);
                        final View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_request_work, null);
                        ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.address))).setText(pushData.area);
                        ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.description))).setText(pushData.name + " " + pushData.tel);
                        ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.rectangleNumber))).setText(pushData.number);
                        (view.findViewById(R.id.agreeBtn)).setOnClickListener(view1 -> agreeRequestWork());
                        (view.findViewById(R.id.disagreeBtn)).setOnClickListener(view1 -> disagreeRequestWork());
                        layout.addView(view);
                        viewMap.put(pushData.idFromServer, view);
                    }
                });
            }
```

Но при изменении в данных в бд вызывается сразу несколько subscribe
Как работать с room в ui потоке по уму, можно конечно добавить разрешение, но везде пишут, что это плохой подход

Comment: Можно очень по разному сделать. Например можете получение данных сделать в виде `Single` (вместо `Flowable`) - тогда у вас по одному разу будет из БД данные браться и не сообщать о новых поступлениях/изменениях.

Comment: а как вызвать @Query("DELETE FROM pushdata")
    void deleteAll(); ? что то типа Single<Void> deleteAll();

Comment: Например так: `Completable.fromCallable(deleteAll())`